# onChange function filter me all items but I can't call all items again?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

i do a drop down search. and on filtering items. But once I filter them, I can’t anymore because they’re already ‘cut’ - filtered. Check my code:

```
      <select class="select" (change)="onCountyChange($event)">
           <option> Filter by region</option>
           <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
               {{ item }}
           </option>
      </select>
```

And in ts file:

```
onCountyChange(e){
  let selectedRegion = e.target.value; 
  this.names = this.names.filter(item => item.name == selectedRegion)
}
```

this.names i array of name.
this.items is array of few names which need be filtered.
The mistake is that once he filters my names, after that he has nothing to filter by other criteria.

Example this.names = ['alex' , 'smith' , 'pedro' , 'Vito'];
this.items = ['alex' , 'pedro'];

My logic work only first time when I filtered by example name alex...Second time when i try to filter with 'pedro' i can;t because in my names is only alex.....

Comment: Share the HTML code that displays filtered results. This will help to understand now you use `this.names` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy to fix.

You can add another property to the class like:

```
filteredNames = this.names;
```

and inside `onCountyChange`:

```
onCountyChange(e){
  let selectedRegion = e.target.value; 
  this.filteredNames = this.names.filter(item => item.name == selectedRegion)
}
```

So this way you'll always filter the array which has all the names.

Comment: I cant friend...my items is already filtered array ....

Comment: You set filteredNames is empty array ? What is on dropdown ? Which values

Comment: Instead of an empty array, you can set it to  `filteredNames = this.names`, if that's what filteredNames should hold initially.

Comment: @bilados Also use `filteredNames` instead of `names` in the HTML.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227420/discussion-between-ramesh-reddy-and-bilados).

Answer (score 1):

Don't filter on the original array i.e `items`. Create a copy of it so that its value doesn't get changed while filtering. For example:

```
  items = ['alex', 'smith', 'pedro', 'Vito'];
  
  onCountyChange(e) {
    let names = Object.assign([], this.items);      
    let selectedRegion = e.target.value;
    names = names.filter(item => item == selectedRegion);
    console.log(names)
  }
```

Here, every time the dropdown value is changed a copy of the original *items* array is created and the filtering is done on that i.e `names`.

Comment: Okay but here what to share in html ?